# Scale y-axis (counts) in ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a simple histogram of data sampled at, say, 10%.  I want counts on the y-axis, but since the data are sampled, I want them to be scaled appropriately.  If I were using base graphics, I'd do something like

```
foo <- rnorm(50)
foo.hist <- hist(foo,plot=F)
foo.hist$counts <- foo.hist$counts * 10
plot(foo.hist)
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this with ggplot2?..  There are all sorts of "canned" y-axis transformations (scale_y_log(), etc); is there something more general-purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(50))
ggplot(df,aes(x))+geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..*10))
```

Comment: Clearly I haven't read Hadley's book carefully enough :P

Now, is there a way to make 10 into a variable?..  The above code won't work if I do factor <- 10; ggplot(df,aes(x))+geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..*factor))

Comment: try this: fac<-10; ggplot(df,aes(x))+geom_histogram(aes(fac=fac,y=..count..*fac))